# After Click Event Instead of Showing all Notes Display only Current Note

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

Program starts with displaying all notes from localstore, but when I click the addButton it display my current note only.

I want to show all the notes and after click event new note will add with previous notes.

```
let addButton = document.querySelector(".addBtn");
let userNotes = [];
displayNotes();
//addButton Event Listner
addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //get the user inputs
    let userInputs = {
        title: document.getElementById("title_input").value,
        description: document.getElementById("des_input").value
    };

    //push user inputs to arrays
    userNotes.push(userInputs);

    document.querySelector("form").reset();

    //store to the localstorage
    localStorage.setItem("Notes", JSON.stringify(userNotes));

    //display to the user
    displayNotes();
});

function displayNotes() {
    let gettingNotes = localStorage.getItem("Notes");

    let allNotes = JSON.parse(gettingNotes);
    let html = "";
    allNotes.forEach(element => {
        html += `
                    <div class="single-item">
                        <h2 class="single-item-title">
                            ${element.title}
                        </h2>
                        <p class="single-item-description">
                            ${element.description}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                `;
    });

    document.querySelector(".item-list").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you set userNotes to be an empty array and you add only your current note. Try to initialize userNotes with a value from localStorage, i.e

```
let userNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Notes')) || []
```

Also, then you are able to use userNotes variable in displayNotes function, instead of allNotes.